# Admin Verification to login

Tags: php, html

How to make a "admin_verify.php" file...where admin will check/verify an user registered in the database? Then the user can login. Other users will be unable to login.

Comment: Stack isn't a "how to"; try something.

Comment: Provide what you tried and then any errors you encountered - see [how do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: submit some code/file then i'll be helping you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In database table where you are saving members data you need to make a field whatever you like in my case i will say **admin_approval**, in that row save 0(zero) initially, then show the requests to in admin panel or whatever the scenario in your case, then admin will mark them as 1 or true.

then in login check page you can easily access the registered members which admin as approved by SQL query like

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM you_table_name WHERE `user_name` = "enter_user_name" AND `user_password` = "user_enter_password" ) as member_login WHERE admin_approval = "1"
```

Comment: I have a question that: - 
with the following code I am able to pass a value to the phpmyadmin database and also disable the button, but I want to keep that button in disabled state even if I refresh the current or call this page from "a.php" ---   


    <td><center>
    <button onclick="window.location.href='a.php?n=<?php echo    
    $c;?>';this.disabled=true; 
    this.innerHTML='Verified'">Verify</button>
    </center></td>

Comment: if you want to keep the button disable try
<button type="button"  disabled="disabled">verify</button>

is will show the button but will be disable no action will be performed on its click.